# Best approach for loading files without absolute paths

Tags: java, web-applications

I am writing an application that uses values from a configuration file to open a connection to a database.

The application belongs to a directory hierarchy that I dictate. Therefore, I know the relative path to my configuration file from my application's root directory.

However, since the users of my application may install the application's root directory anywhere, I don't know the absolute path of the root directory ahead of time.

What is the best strategy for finding the configuration file (or any file, for that matter)? How are similar issues typically handled in well coded applications?

Many thanks!

Comment: For whoever is interested, I found this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll say this very strongly, with bold face and everything: **don't write code that assumes a relative path will work**.  At my job, my predecessors wrote code like this all over the place, and now that we've grown a lot and need to integrate with other Java applications, it's a nightmare.  It only works if you can guarantee that the JVM will be started up with your desired directory as the current directory—and when you start embedding your code in third-party containers you won't have any control over it.

The best way of getting ahold of files  is, as asgs mentions in a comment to your question, is to use `ClassLoader.getResource(String path)` and related methods (e.g., `Class.getResourceAsStream(String path)`, as mentioned in asgs's link).  This has some minor problems if used the way it works right off the shelf; mainly, the idea of putting one's database configuration file in the application jar file or classpath is, frankly, absurd.

However, **that can be fixed**.  By using a ClassLoader to access a resource, you're basically delegating the job of finding that resource to the ClassLoader, so later when you want to change the location where the file is read from you just need to replace the default ClassLoader with something that does what you want.  (Whereas if you do as my old coworkers did and rely on relative filesystem path, you're screwed.)

ClassLoaders also allow you to do other tricks, like obtaining the configuration file over HTTP—this can be useful in cloud or cluster applications.